# How can Users from a company download private apps

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

In order to keep our react-native app updateable and private, we decided to use [this approach](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-publish-private-apps-in-google-play/) to upload an APK to the Play Store privately. Apparently, our client has to have G Suite set up for this to work. I suppose, with G Suite, the client can "add" user accounts to the company and with that, somehow allow them to download our app (by whitelisting it?).

But how/where can the Users download and install the private app after it has been published? Can they just search for it on the play store and see/download it there?

Comment: I think you need to make your own store portal on Google Play..  I was looking into this a while back, the best solution was to release a beta version and add people to the beta testers..

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139?hl=en